# qtcreator cannot find omp.h and any function from openmp

Tags: qt, mingw, openmp, qt-creator, qmake

I'm trying to make poject on c++ with openmp on Windows (MSVS has own errors). I added this lines into .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+= -fopenmp
QMAKE_LFLAGS +=  -fopenmp
```

But qt creator still says, that he cannot find <omp.h> file  ( file also) and any function from openmp.
What i did wrong?

Edit: `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw810_64\lib\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\8.1.0\include` contains omp.h header:

[image]

Comment: You should tell the compiler where it can find the headers you want to use -> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#includepath